# Jest concurrency - global setup with Firebase app

Tags: firebase, jestjs

I'm using jest `globalSetup` to run an async script that looks something like:

```
module.exports = async () => {
    const secrets = await decryptSecrets()
    const app = admin.initializeApp({ ...secrets })
}
```

However, my test suites fail when requiring modules with firebase, with the following error:
`The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.`

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
describe('example', () => {
    test('test', async () => {
        const users = await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .get()
        expect(users.docs).toHaveLength(1)

    })
})
```

To the best of my knowledge, this is because Jest runs tests concurrency and they import modules completely separately, and it isn't aware of the global firebase app.

How should I handle this? I do not import firebase app singletons anywhere in my node/express app and this would take a long time to replace.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I believe we initialize an admin SDK app before every test suite... can get back to you

Comment: Could you please share your solution here for others.